# Accessing and printing nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having trouble reaching nested keys in the following object. 
I'm trying to print all the "kilometers_per_second" within "relative_velocity" inside "close_approach_data".

I get back an error and don't understand what I'm doing wrong. 
Thank you in advance

```
const asteroidData = near_earth_objects
        .map((data) => data.close_approach_data[0])
        .map((e) => e.relative_velocity); 

// TypeError: Cannot read property 'relative_velocity' of undefined

or

const asteroidData = near_earth_objects
          .map((data) => data.close_approach_data[0].relative_velocity);

// TypeError: Cannot read property 'relative_velocity' of undefined
```

JSON object:

```
 "near_earth_objects": [
        {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/2021277?api_key=24TE7EgNfmXIvdb6vNNZGBWx8s54XbZzCCi2oAdN"
            },
            "id": "2021277",
            "neo_reference_id": "2021277",
            "name": "21277 (1996 TO5)",
            "designation": "21277",
            "nasa_jpl_url": "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2021277",
            "absolute_magnitude_h": 16.1,
            "estimated_diameter": {
                "kilometers": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 1.6016033798,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 3.5812940302
                },
                "meters": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 1601.6033797856,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 3581.2940301941
                },
                "miles": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 0.9951898937,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 2.2253122528
                },
                "feet": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 5254.6044325359,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 11749.652706022
                }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": false,
            "close_approach_data": [
                {
                    "close_approach_date": "1945-06-07",
                    "close_approach_date_full": "1945-Jun-07 22:35",
                    "epoch_date_close_approach": -775272300000,
                    "relative_velocity": {
                        "kilometers_per_second": "15.5094751879",
                        "kilometers_per_hour": "55834.1106763388",
                        "miles_per_hour": "34693.1450477507"
                    },
                    "miss_distance": {
                        "astronomical": "0.0334232973",
                        "lunar": "13.0016626497",
                        "kilometers": "5000054.084456751",
                        "miles": "3106889.5396991238"
                    },
                    "orbiting_body": "Mars"
                }
            ],
            "is_sentry_object": false
        },

       // Object continues repeating the above structure
```

Comment: That error can occur if any of the main objects don't have a `close_approach_data` array or the array is empty. Start by confirming each object is populated with that property and that it indeed has a `data.close_approach_data[0]`

Comment: Check your json object .  It is not valid .At the start it should const near_earth_objects= [] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need all the values or just the `kilometers_per_second` values?

```js
let near_earth_objects =  [
        {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/2021277?api_key=24TE7EgNfmXIvdb6vNNZGBWx8s54XbZzCCi2oAdN"
            },
            "id": "2021277",
            "neo_reference_id": "2021277",
            "name": "21277 (1996 TO5)",
            "designation": "21277",
            "nasa_jpl_url": "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2021277",
            "absolute_magnitude_h": 16.1,
            "estimated_diameter": {
                "kilometers": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 1.6016033798,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 3.5812940302
                },
                "meters": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 1601.6033797856,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 3581.2940301941
                },
                "miles": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 0.9951898937,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 2.2253122528
                },
                "feet": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 5254.6044325359,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 11749.652706022
                }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": false,
            "close_approach_data": [
                {
                    "close_approach_date": "1945-06-07",
                    "close_approach_date_full": "1945-Jun-07 22:35",
                    "epoch_date_close_approach": -775272300000,
                    "relative_velocity": {
                        "kilometers_per_second": "15.5094751879",
                        "kilometers_per_hour": "55834.1106763388",
                        "miles_per_hour": "34693.1450477507"
                    },
                    "miss_distance": {
                        "astronomical": "0.0334232973",
                        "lunar": "13.0016626497",
                        "kilometers": "5000054.084456751",
                        "miles": "3106889.5396991238"
                    },
                    "orbiting_body": "Mars"
                }
            ],
            "is_sentry_object": false
        }];
        
let result = near_earth_objects.flatMap(({close_approach_data }) => close_approach_data.map(({relative_velocity})=> relative_velocity.kilometers_per_second));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ifaruki. I just need the "kilometers_per_second" values. How would I reach that one please?

Comment: @Paolo_T yes, i have updated the code, it should only filter `kilometers_per_second`

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine, just need to convert raw json "near_earth_objects"

**example**

```
const near_earth_objects = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('YOUR_NEAR_EARTH')).near_earth_objects; 
const asteroidData = near_earth_objects
         .map((data) => data.close_approach_data[0].relative_velocity);
```

check this one

```js
const near_earth_objects_json = 
{ "near_earth_objects" : [
        {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/2021277?api_key=24TE7EgNfmXIvdb6vNNZGBWx8s54XbZzCCi2oAdN"
            },
            "id": "2021277",
            "neo_reference_id": "2021277",
            "name": "21277 (1996 TO5)",
            "designation": "21277",
            "nasa_jpl_url": "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2021277",
            "absolute_magnitude_h": 16.1,
            "estimated_diameter": {
                "kilometers": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 1.6016033798,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 3.5812940302
                },
                "meters": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 1601.6033797856,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 3581.2940301941
                },
                "miles": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 0.9951898937,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 2.2253122528
                },
                "feet": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 5254.6044325359,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 11749.652706022
                }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": false,
            "close_approach_data": [
                {
                    "close_approach_date": "1945-06-07",
                    "close_approach_date_full": "1945-Jun-07 22:35",
                    "epoch_date_close_approach": -775272300000,
                    "relative_velocity": {
                        "kilometers_per_second": "15.5094751879",
                        "kilometers_per_hour": "55834.1106763388",
                        "miles_per_hour": "34693.1450477507"
                    },
                    "miss_distance": {
                        "astronomical": "0.0334232973",
                        "lunar": "13.0016626497",
                        "kilometers": "5000054.084456751",
                        "miles": "3106889.5396991238"
                    },
                    "orbiting_body": "Mars"
                }
            ],
            "is_sentry_object": false
        },
        {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/2021277?api_key=24TE7EgNfmXIvdb6vNNZGBWx8s54XbZzCCi2oAdN"
            },
            "id": "2021277",
            "neo_reference_id": "2021277",
            "name": "21277 (1996 TO5)",
            "designation": "21277",
            "nasa_jpl_url": "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2021277",
            "absolute_magnitude_h": 16.1,
            "estimated_diameter": {
                "kilometers": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 1.6016033798,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 3.5812940302
                },
                "meters": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 1601.6033797856,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 3581.2940301941
                },
                "miles": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 0.9951898937,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 2.2253122528
                },
                "feet": {
                    "estimated_diameter_min": 5254.6044325359,
                    "estimated_diameter_max": 11749.652706022
                }
            },
            "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": false,
            "close_approach_data": [
                {
                    "close_approach_date": "1945-06-07",
                    "close_approach_date_full": "1945-Jun-07 22:35",
                    "epoch_date_close_approach": -775272300000,
                    "relative_velocity": {
                        "kilometers_per_second": "15.5094751879",
                        "kilometers_per_hour": "55834.1106763388",
                        "miles_per_hour": "34693.1450477507"
                    },
                    "miss_distance": {
                        "astronomical": "0.0334232973",
                        "lunar": "13.0016626497",
                        "kilometers": "5000054.084456751",
                        "miles": "3106889.5396991238"
                    },
                    "orbiting_body": "Mars"
                }
            ],
            "is_sentry_object": false
        } ]
   }     


const near_earth_objects = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(near_earth_objects_json)).near_earth_objects;

const asteroidData = near_earth_objects
         .map((data) => data.close_approach_data[0].relative_velocity);
        console.log(asteroidData);
```

If you want only `kilometers_per_second`, you can do like

```
const asteroidData = near_earth_objects
          .map((data) => data.close_approach_data[0].relative_velocity.kilometers_per_second);
```

Comment: Thanks pich_chaya for your help. 
One question: 
Can you explain what should I put instead of  'YOUR_NEAR_EARTH'?

Comment: In this case it is your raw JSON object >> ` "near_earth_objects": [
        {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/2021277?api_key=24TE7EgNfmXIvdb6vNNZGBWx8s54XbZzCCi2oAdN"
            },
            "id": "2021277",
            "neo_reference_id": "2021277",
            "name": "21277 (1996 TO5)",
            "designation": "21277",
            "nasa_jpl_url": "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2021277",
            "absolute_magnitude_h": 16.1, ...`